# Can I work around dead spots on my touchscreen with a custom keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard

I have dead spots on my touchscreen, right on the soft keyboard area. Is there a way I can use a custom keyboard layout or move my keyboard to work around the problem until I replace my phone?

Answer (score 0):

Try swift keyboard - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey

This allows full customization of your keyboard size.

Comment: Swiftkey only propose 5 different keyboard sizes. I want more customization (keys size, prediction bar...)